# PgAdmin 4 unable to connect to the server on mac, i have postgres 14

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

PgAdmin 4 unable to connect to the server on mac, i have postgres 14
[screenshot of problem, server can not be connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuY43.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can Run this in terminal

1. brew services stop postgresql
2. pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start